# postProcessAfterInitialization() is not called only for beans from one jar

Tags: java, spring, spring-bean

We have multiple modules in our project. I have introduced impl class for BeanPostProcessor and expects that postProcessAfterInitialization() method will be called for beans from each and every module in the product. It works in similar manner except for all the beans from one jar.

I have introduced the imp in 2.jar like

```
@Component
public class RBACCheckingBeanPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor, PriorityOrdered, BeanClassLoaderAware
{
    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException
    {}
}
```

There is another module 1.jar in which I have controller class

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/epn", produces = "application/json")
public class EPNController
{
}
```

There are also other jars which have controller classes.

The problem is that postProcessAfterInitialization is not called for EPNController bean and all other beans in 1.jar. But I can see that there is call back from controller classes from other jars including 2.jar.

For troubleshooting purpose I have moded RBACCheckingBeanPostProcessor to 1.jar and now I can see the callbacks for EPNController bean.

I do not understand what could be the problem if I have BeanPostProcessor in 2.jar.

Answer (score 0):

I could resolve the issue. The problem was with @Configuration class. Both 1.jar and 2.jar had @Configuration class. I had to import the @Configuration class from 2.jar in @Configuration class of 1.jar.
Now I can see that BeanPostProcessor methods are called for beans created in 1.jar also..